# JDeveloper won't run on 64-bit Ubuntu

Tags: 64-bit, oracle

After installing JDeveloper 11.1.1.6.0 on 64-bit Ubuntu 12.04, it refuses to start.  It says it can't find `libxext.so.6`.  I can see that `libxext.so.6` does exist on the machine.  Making a symlink to it in JDeveloper's own lib directory doesn't work because it's a 64-bit library, and JDeveloper is set up as 32-bit.  How can we get the needed library installed so JDeveloper can run?

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to solve the problem either, but I chose the *.jar (Generic) installer of JDeveloper instead of the bin one and now it runs without a problem. I hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

You can fix this by editing file %JDEV_HOME%/jdev/bin/jdev.conf and change the line start with setJavaHome to a valid 64bit JDK. That fix my problem. Hope this can help you.